# Script for call routing through asterisk server

Tags: php, routes, asterisk

How can I get a script in which I can route a call using an asterisk server (script may be in PHP or CGI). Actually, I have an agent interface in PHP and I want to make a call using this agent interface, e.g. on a button click.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at FreePBX.org, that might be able to get you started